# How do I set font size to 0px in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have an unordered list, I'm trying to hide the text in the list. I can do this 2 ways that i know of:

font-color: transparent;
font-size: 0px;

I prefer the 0px method as its not selectable. This issue is neither way works in IE6. The first way just doesn't work in IE6 at all, the 2nd leave a 1PX high font.

Is there a way to hide the text in IE6?

This is a visual thing, I know you can read the text by reading the source and that is OK, I just need it to visually not be there.

Comment: 0px fonts make no sense and probably cause lots of division by 0 errors in the font libraries used by the OS and browser. Also, can't you just set the containing element to not display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
display: none;

visibility: hidden;

text-indent: -9999px;
```

Comment: text-indent: -9999px;

that did the trick, thanks!

display: none, "removed" the div, visibility: hidden; hid the background image/color.

Answer (score 0):

`text-indent: -777em; width: FOO; overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you mark the text in a span with a special class? This way you can use:

```
span.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It will have some custom markup (like a span) anyway, otherwise the OP couldn't choose the options he wrote in his question.